# Определение местоположения Android с высокой точностью

Tags: android, google-api, android-location

Вопрос как организовать автоматическое определение местоположения дивайса с высокой точностью. Понятно что ловим изменение координат в onLocationChanged, но как узнать что координаты точные и не требуют дальнейших уточнений? Вот есть метод

`LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);`

И вот такой LocationRequest

`protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10 * 1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        mLocationRequest.setNumUpdates(3);//как пример
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }`

При таком LocationRequest дивайс врубит GPS или ГЛОНАС и будет себя позиционировать. Суть вопроса в том, когда первый раз сработает onLocationChanged то не факт что координаты будут точными, например при следующем обновлении может быть уточнение, точно так же как третье изменение координат может оказаться менее точным чем второе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `Location` есть [метод `float getAccuracy()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy%28%29), возвращающий ожидаемую погрешность этого местоположения в метрах, или `0.0`, если данные о точности отсутствуют.

Система не может заранее знать, сможет ли она уточнить координаты по сравнению с тем, что есть сейчас, потому что это зависит от внешних условий, а не от самой системы. Навигационных спутников может быть видно мало, сигнал плохой, что угодно.

---

Можно установить порог точности по умолчанию на ожидаемую "сносную точность" навигации, имеющую смысл для приложения. Если данных о точности нет совсем, приложение всё равно будет работать, поскольку погрешность будет "якобы нулевой".

Также стоит сделать возможность её ручной настройки для печальных случаев.

Можно также извернуться и сделать автонастройку, которая автоматически повысит допустимую погрешность, если длительное время будут поступать неточные данные.

Впрочем, это уже предположения о приложении.

Comment: Правильно я понял, что getAccuracy() - порог точности, что при попадании в эту точность система сама перестанет обновлять координаты?  А вообще по сути вопроса, чтобы наверняка то нужно UI и чтоб юзер сам подтвердил свое местоположение.

Comment: @ИльяШашилов нет, `Location` же представляет конкретную точку, конкретное положение, известное на данный момент. Объект этого типа прилетает в `onLocationChanged`. Впоследствии, возможно, прилетит `Location` с другой точностью. Выше ли, ниже ли, как знать.

Comment: Это понятно. Ну вот у меня стоит mLocationRequest.setNumUpdates(3) - это значит что система тупо после трех обновлений отрубит GPS. Как сделать красиво, чтобы система сама поняла что текущее обновление точное, и можно вырубить GPS, а то батарея не вечная :) В каких то случаях может быть будет достаточно одного обновления, а в каких то 3 ех будет мало. Это понятно что зависит от внешних условий.  Для случая  бункера можно поставить таймер отрубающий GPS.

Comment: @ИльяШашилов описал выше. Либо когда достгинута точность, выше которой уже нет смысла, либо если точность уже N времени не повышалась. Как вариант.

Comment: ОК. Буду пробовать на практике, надеюсь тогда станет понятнее :)

Comment: отменил принятый ответ потому что ни фига мне не понятно. Видимо я деревянный. Сделал эксперимент. При нажатии кнопки запускается `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);`. В методе onLocationChanged вывожу в лог данные по точности. В итоге точность скачет туда сюда. то 39, то 107, то 46, то 58. Если мне надо чтоб было не больше 5 метров, то у меня так батарейка может сесть у дивайса пока дождусь.Дай пример кода как обработать данные по точности, и если точность достигнута то закончить обновление локации.

Comment: @ИльяШашилов это как раз момент, в котором каждое приложение решает само, как ему выбирать местоположение. Надо побольше данных собрать. Скажем, выводить ещё и `getProvider`, можно ещё и `getExtras`. Может, там от GPS не приходит ничего.